# BigQuery BashScript-- Not transferring to the destination

Tags: bash, google-bigquery

I wrote a simple bash script to that takes the results from a query and appends them to an existing table.  My script executes but the data doesn't seem to make it to the destination table.   Any idea what i might be doing wrong?  is it possible that I can't use a partition ($) as a destination?

Thank you so much for your help.

```
#!/bin/bash
bq query \
--destination_table=logs.p_activity_428001$20170803 \
--append_table <<EOF
SELECT 
*
FROM log.p_activity_428001
where _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-08-03')

EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar sign; `bash` is expanding the positional parameter `$20170803`, which is empty unless you provide 20,170,803 arguments to the script. A single backslash will suffice:

```
#!/bin/bash
bq query \
--destination_table=logs.p_activity_428001\$20170803 \
--append_table <<EOF
SELECT 
*
FROM log.p_activity_428001
where _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-08-03')

EOF
```

although single-quoting the whole table name may be more readable:

```
#!/bin/bash
bq query \
--destination_table='logs.p_activity_428001$20170803' \
--append_table <<EOF
SELECT 
*
FROM log.p_activity_428001
where _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2017-08-03')

EOF
```